# Can I rebuild windows.edb when the programs are running in Win10?

Tags: windows

My program needs to consistently read and write a large amount of small files for days. As a result, the windows.edb file will gradually grow to extreme large (~ 245GB), then Windows Search will take most of CPU (more than 80%) and force my CPU to run with 100% usage. So can I release the windows.edb through rebuilding the windows.edb when my program is running? Or is there any other way to solve my problem? Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you really need all those files to be indexed and searchable?

Comment: @dxiv Even all the files are indexed, the windows.edb should not be that large. The problem is that the indexed contents constantly accumulate to the windows.edb file. After reading your comment, I googled and found that turning off indexing may help. I will take a try. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't need the files to be indexed, just create them in a way or in a place such that they are excluded from Windows search.

Comment: @dxiv Yes, I have done like you said and it works. The search index can take up a larger percentage if there are lots of very small files. In this case, turning off indexing for a specific location is really helpful. Thanks!